# Java Beginner: How do I link one linked list to another?

Tags: java, linked-list

If I have: `linkedlist1= 1,2,3,4;` and   `linkedlist2= 5,6,7;`

Am I able to attach linkedlist2 to the end of linkedlist1 in such a way if I invoke: `linkedlist2.set(0,9999)`  it changes to `linkedlist2 = [999,6,7]` and  `linkedlist1` becomes `[1,2,3,4,9999,7,8];` ?

Is that possible ? Or I do need another structure ?

The following code didn't work:

```
 List<Double> l1 = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(1.0,2.0));
 List<Double> l2 = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(3.0,4.0));
 l1.addAll(l2);
 System.out.println(l1);
 l2.set(0, 9.0);
 System.out.println(l1);
```

OUTPUT:

```
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Comment: When asking a question never say "code didn't work".  Instead explain what result you expected and what you got.  Otherwise it is really confusing because technically the code is working just not the way you want.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There may be a way to do this that is a better design than having two completely separate ways to modify the same object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard LinkedList classes provided with Java lack this capability.

As Donal Boyle posts you can add the contents of one list to another but this doesn't maintain the linkage as your describe.

Comment: so which data structure does provide this capability?

Comment: I don't know of anyone that provides one.  You could write one that conforms to the LinkedList interface but provides some new methods for this type of splicing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't but as an alternative you can have a list of list, but I don't know if that would work as you need:

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;
class ListOfLists { 
  public static void main( String ... args ) { 

    List<Integer> a = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
    List<Integer> b = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5,6,7));  

    List<List> list = new LinkedList<List>();
    list.add( a );
    list.add( b );

    out.println("Before : " + list );
    b.set( 0, 999 );

    out.println("After  : " + list );

  }
}

Before : [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
After  : [[1, 2, 3, 4], [999, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about updating one list and seeing the updates reflected in the other, the answer is it depends.

If you update an object in the first list you will see a change. but if you replace the object you will not see the change. Calling .set() on the first list is replacing the object in the list. Unfortunately, it is not possible to update the value of a primitive (or its class representation, in this case Float) without replacing it.

To append two lists, assuming you are using java.util.LinkedList, you can call [addAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: I have added some more information to my answer regarding why this will not work for the objects you are putting in the list.

Answer (score 0):

`addAll()` just takes the values from the second linked list.  Changes to the indexes and set values in the second list will not affect the first.  (Note: changes to the objects themselves will stay because they both point to the same object).

You can make a List of Lists if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: nope I already had a list of a list and was using addall to add lists, but now I just need flat linked list where the last element of it is connected to the first element of the other

Comment: Then combine the lists with AddAll().  The objects in the list are the same, so if you use something that is not immutable this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to have a proper class for your items and have instances of this class `MyInt` link to each other in stead of relying on LinkedList, i.e. add a `MyInt next;`  field to the custom class that holds your integers.
Then link them as described.
A change to one instance can then be done without even touching the list structure and is reflected accordingly when iterating over this list through the `next` references.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be a nice application for the [subList(int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method:

```
List<Double> l1 = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0));
List<Double> l2 = l1.subList(2, 4);
```

Alas, the JavaDoc of subList states:

> The semantics of the list returned by
>   this method become undefined if the
>   backing list (i.e., this list) is
>   *structurally modified* in any way other
>   than via the returned list.
>   (Structural modifications are those
>   that change the size of this list, or
>   otherwise perturb it in such a fashion
>   that iterations in progress may yield
>   incorrect results.)

So if you want to use a method like `.add` on l1, then you may be out of luck. In fact, for all *fail-fast* list classes derived from `AbstractList` (such as as `LinkedList`), subList should throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` after the parent list of a subList was structurally modified.

However, if you stay away from structural modifications in the parent list (or if you re-create the sub-list after such modifications), then everything will work as expected.