# Concat linked lists in constant time complexity O(1) in Kotlin or Java

Tags: java, kotlin, linked-list, concatenation

What I am doing is concatenating dynamically generated linked lists, only 2 at a time. How to do this in constant time complexity O(1) in Kotlin or Java?

[This similar question in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303986/concatenate-two-java-util-linkedlist-in-constant-time) tells me that `java.util.LinkedList` doesn't support adding in constant time. And the Google Guava [`Iterators.concat`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#concat-java.util.Iterator-java.util.Iterator-) can only combine 2 or more iterators in one call, which causes multiple layers of wrapping and adds complexity when iterating in my case.

Comment: Do you really want to return a `LinkedList` ? Or would it be ok to implement a new List which would wrap several `LinkedList` and that would get elements in those underlying LinkedList ?

Comment: I think both can work. The wrapping is fine as long as it doesn't add nonconstant complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kotlin you can combine multiple `Iterator`s using the `iterator {...}` function like this:

```
fun <T> combine(a: Iterator<T>, b: Iterator<T>, c: Iterator<T>): Iterator<T> {
  return iterator {
    yieldAll(a)
    yieldAll(b)
    yieldAll(c)
  }
}
```

This function returns an `Iterator` of type `T` which lazily consumes `a` then `b` and finally `c`

The solution would be something like this:

```
fun <T> combine(vararg iterators: Iterator<T>): Iterator<T> {
  return iterator {
    iterators.forEach { yieldAll(it) }
  }
}
```

This implementation takes `n` iterators and combines them into one.

Comment: I see but what this function does is the same to Google Guava `Iterators.concat`. It creates an iterator that wraps multiple iterators. In my case when such lists are dynamically generated, I concat lists 2 at a time. This can cause multiple layers of wrapping and adds complexity when iterating.

Comment: I think I was wrong about this iterator wrapping paradigm. If given the assumption that a combined iterator wrapper wraps at least 2 iterators, and each linked list iterator has at least 1 element, then it forms a tree data structure and iteration aka traversal can be completed in O(n) time, because the number of all elements >= the number of leaf nodes (linked list iterators) > 1/2 the number of all nodes (all iterator instances). Maybe you should edit your answer to 1. filter out empty iterators and 2. return the original iterator if there is only one left, then I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a simple version of singly linked list based on Java's `LinkedList` only to support this concat function. For simplicity, it only implements `Iterable` instead of `List`:

Java implementation:

```java
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class SimpleLinkedList<E> implements Iterable<E> {
    Node<E> first;
    Node<E> last;

    static class Node<E> {
        E item;
        Node<E> next;

        Node(E item, Node<E> next) {
            this.item = item;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    static class NodeIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
        private Node<E> node;

        NodeIterator(Node<E> node) {
            this.node = node;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return node != null;
        }

        public E next() {
            Node<E> currentNode = node;
            if (currentNode == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
            node = currentNode.next;
            return currentNode.item;
        }
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new NodeIterator<>(first);
    }

    public void add(E element) {
        // Copied from java.util.LinkedList
        Node l = last;
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(element, null);
        last = newNode;
        if (l == null)
            first = newNode;
        else
            l.next = newNode;
    }

    public void concatWith(SimpleLinkedList other) {
        if (last != null) last.next = other.first;
        else first = other.first;

        if (other.last != null) last = other.last;
    }
}
```

Kotlin implementation:

```
class SimpleLinkedList<E> : Iterable<E> {
    var first: Node<E>? = null
    var last: Node<E>? = null

    class Node<E>(var item: E, var next: Node<E>? = null)
    class NodeIterator<E>(var node: Node<E>?) : Iterator<E> {
        override fun hasNext(): Boolean = node != null
        override fun next(): E {
            val currentNode = node
            if (currentNode === null) throw NoSuchElementException()
            node = currentNode.next
            return currentNode.item
        }
    }

    override fun iterator(): Iterator<E> = NodeIterator(first)

    fun add(element: E) {
        // Copied from java.util.LinkedList
        val l = last
        val newNode = Node(element, null)
        last = newNode
        if (l == null)
            first = newNode
        else
            l.next = newNode
    }

    infix fun concatWith(other: SimpleLinkedList<E>) {
        last.run {
            if (this !== null) next = other.first
            else first = other.first
        }
        other.last?.let { last = it }
    }
}
```

The Kotlin implementation is actually a little bit slower than the Java one because getters and setters are used to access properties.